# Using nf_conntrack_bridge with Debian 11

Tags: debian, netfilter, conntrack

I'm trying to use conntrack under Debian 11, but I cannot load the kernel module:

```
# modprobe nf_conntrack_bridge.ko
modprobe: FATAL: Module nf_conntrack_bridge.ko not found in directory /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve
```

The kernel module is in the modules:

```
# find /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve -name '*conntrack*' -ls                  
 22942804     96 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        94696 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/bridge/netfilter/nf_conntrack_bridge.ko
 22943003      8 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         6848 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_broadcast.ko
 22943001    548 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       559976 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack.ko
 22943009    112 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       111784 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_pptp.ko
 22943005    212 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       216312 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_h323.ko
 22943012     12 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         8728 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_snmp.ko
 22943008    160 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       162680 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_netlink.ko
 22943007      8 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root         7896 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_netbios_ns.ko
 22943097     16 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        13608 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/xt_conntrack.ko
 22943011    132 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       132112 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_sip.ko
 22943006     20 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        19336 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_irc.ko 
 22943004    108 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root       110272 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_ftp.ko
 22943010     20 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        16568 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_sane.ko
 22943002     92 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        93160 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_amanda.ko
 22943013     96 -rw-r--r--   1 root     root        95296 sept. 22 10:11 /lib/modules/5.11.22-4-pve/kernel/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tftp.ko
```

With Debian 10 I could use `xt_conntrack`:

```
modprobe xt_conntrack
```

```
lsmod | grep conn
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns    16384  0
nf_conntrack_netlink    45056  0
nf_conntrack_h323      81920  1 nf_nat_h323
nf_conntrack_sip       36864  1 nf_nat_sip
nf_conntrack_ftp       24576  1 nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack_amanda    16384  1 nf_nat_amanda
nf_conntrack_pptp      24576  1 nf_nat_pptp
nf_conntrack_tftp      20480  1 nf_nat_tftp
nf_conntrack_sane      20480  0
xt_conntrack           16384  58
nf_conntrack_snmp      16384  1 nf_nat_snmp_basic
nf_conntrack_irc       20480  1 nf_nat_irc
nf_conntrack_broadcast    16384  2 nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_snmp
nf_conntrack_bridge    16384  0
nf_conntrack          139264  26 xt_conntrack,nf_nat_irc,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_tftp,nf_nat_ftp,nf_conntrack_pptp,nft_nat,nf_conntrack_netbios_ns,nf_conntrack_sane,xt_nat,nf_nat_tftp,nf_nat_amanda,nf_conntrack_sip,nf_conntrack_h323,nf_nat_pptp,nf_conntrack_broadcast,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_conntrack_amanda,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_nat_h323,nf_conntrack_bridge,nf_conntrack_snmp,nf_nat_snmp_basic,xt_MASQUERADE,nf_nat_sip
nf_defrag_ipv6         24576  2 nf_conntrack,nf_conntrack_bridge
nf_defrag_ipv4         16384  1 nf_conntrack
nfnetlink              16384  11 nft_compat,nfnetlink_acct,nf_conntrack_netlink,nf_tables,ip_set,nfnetlink_log
x_tables               45056  19 ebtables,ip6table_filter,xt_conntrack,ip6table_raw,iptable_filter,nft_compat,xt_LOG,xt_multiport,xt_tcpudp,xt_addrtype,ebt_snat,xt_nat,ip6_tables,ebt_dnat,iptable_raw,ip_tables,xt_MASQUERADE,iptable_mangle,xt_mark
libcrc32c              16384  5 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,raid456,sctp
```

Any idea on what I could resolve that?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do not put the extension .ko

```
modprobe nf_conntrack_bridge
```

Also, do not forget to review your sysctl variables:

```
sudo sysctl -a | grep net.bridge.bridge-nf-*
```

Comment: Silly me! Thanks a lot! What are the use of the net.bridge.bridge-nf-* values?

Comment: See https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Net.bridge.bridge-nf-call_and_sysctl.conf